# What is the equivalent of Visual Studio Command Window in Netbeans

Tags: visual-studio, netbeans, ide

In Visual Studio the command window allows me to write code and test while my program is running. As an example the following may print length of an string in C++:
`? strlen("abcd");`

Is there such a feature in Netbeans?
**EDIT:**
 I'm actually trying to see the content of a string. The strings contains some special characters (e.g. \u202C) which do not have a visual representation and cannot be seen using the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE1**

Sorry for my previous answer. Actually there is such a functionality (in version 7.2.1)

[image]

It is the code evaluator feature. You can access it using the `CTRL+f9` when you are in debug mode.

But unfortunately there is no option to view string's escaped characters.

**UPDATE2**

But you can print these escaped characters. Consider my question here [Print String with escape non printable characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103660/print-string-with-escape-non-printable-characters/17104109#comment24745034_17104109)

I think this works pretty well

[image]